# Is SQLite able to update or insert

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

I am facing a problem in Xcode : I tried many weeks to add data into sqlite database and I surf Google for many results but none of them can give a complete and clear tutorial, most of them are using .db but not sqlite, I suspect that sqlite is not able to insert or update, just can read data, or is there any other way to do it?

Please attach the link with tutorial in the answer if you guys have any. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> I suspect that sqlite is not able to insert or update, just can read
>   data

Of course you can insert data in SQLite. This is a database just as other ones, just a little lighter and embedded in the same process as your application instead of a different one as is usually the case (this both means SQLite can't answer to more than one client, and that you don't have to install anything on the computer apart your application).

Here's the INSERT documentation : http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

And here's a tutorial among many other ones : http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iPhone_Application

(in fact I just googled for "sqlite xcode insert", I didn't knew this tutorial before)

Comment: I had found quite number of tutorials that are really working with Insert and Update, and most of them are in .db format, when I put into my coding which is working with .sqlite, it just not working.. I am quite frustrated with iPhone Programming now... Android gives better programming experience to me compare to it...

Comment: Maybe there is a confusion : with the sqlite engine you can open ".db" files. This is just the name of the file.

Comment: @Sunny probably your problem is that you're trying to write to the read-only database in the bundle. Copy the database to your application's documents directory and perform insert / update operations on that one.

Comment: is there any tutorial available for me?
what I want to do is the sqlite will update automatically when user perform certain action, there is no textfield or button...
For example, I want to update a counter of a viewed video, so when user view the video the database will update itself, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sunny it's been two days that im working to find out how to insert data to sqlite on iOS. First thing you should do is to tell SQLite to where save the data. By default if you run ur app on ur phone it will put the sqlite file in a readonly root. to solve it you should do this :

```
-(NSString *)GetDocumentDirectory{
    fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    homeDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    return homeDir;
}
```

which fileMgr is `NSFileManager` and homeDir is `NSString` next when you wanna insert yout data, first u should give ur SQLite root to it, which is the first line, and it checks if `sqlite3_open` and  will start to insert your data:

```
-(void)InsertRecords:(NSMutableString *)myData{
NSString *dbPath = [self.GetDocumentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YOUR SQLITE FILE NAME.sqlite"];
    const char *dbpath = [dbPath UTF8String];
    sqlite3 *contactDB;
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO tableName (tableColumn) VALUES (\"%@\")", myData];
const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [myData UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
} 
else {
            NSLog(@"error");
}
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }
}
```

hope it helps :)